# Get all datetimes between two datetime based on interval

Tags: php, datetime

Lets take two datetimes 2013-07-22 and 2013-07-28. The datetimes between these two datetimes are 2013-07-23, 2013-07-24, 2013-07-25, 2013-07-26, 2013-07-27, 2013-07-28.

I am able to get this much to work using php datetime.

```
 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 days');
 $period = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
```

### What I Require

I have another variable `$interval` which can take values 1,2,3...**.** If `$interval = 2` then `$period` will only contain 2013-07-24, 2013-07-26 , 2013-07-28.
Likewise `$interval = 3` then `$period` will only contain 2013-07-25, 2013-07-28.

How can do this?

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried `$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('2 days');` ? Also next time please remove useless info like `00:00:00` it makes your question more difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create any interval with that variable, just write:

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("$interval days");
```

instead and you are set.